# When is nonstopmode not nonstopmode?

Tags: errors, pdftex

I had previously understood that typing
    `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode`
was the same as having \nonstopmode in the preamble, and that, furthermore, the typesetting would not stop on finding an error. Neither are evidently the case. The following MWE will stop at the error, even using the command above. However, if \nonstopmode is uncommented, the compilation proceeds nonstop to the end, as expected. Also, if jfm.cls is replaced by article.cls the behavior is also as expected -- that is, using the above command the compilation proceeds to the end, even when \nonstopmode is commented out.

Now, jfm.cls is a journal class file, that can be downloaded from 
 http://arxmliv.kwarc.info/sty/jfm.cls
I haven't looked into it to see what the problem might be. However, that's not really the point. The point is that something in this class file is preventing -`pdflatex interaction=nonstopmode` from working as advertised, and it behaves differently from putting \nonstopmode in the preamble. Using TeXlive 2017.

Either I am missing something (usually the case), or something is amiss; In any case, here is the MWE and any suggestions as to what is going on would be appreciated.

```
%\documentclass{article}  
\documentclass{jfm}  
%\nonstopmode
\begin{document}
Here is an error: a^b
\end{document}`
```

Hee is the log file, obtained using `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex` I had to type 'r' for the compilation to continue.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.10.4)  12 MAR 2018 22:33
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/Users/gkv/latex/sty/jfm.cls
Document Class: jfm 2006/11/13 v1.27 Journal of Fluid Mechanics document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2016/05/09 v1.0r Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.10 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 96.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count79
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen102
\Gin@req@width=\dimen103
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count80
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsfbi on input line 183.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathsfbi on input line 183.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsfbi' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/sl --> T1/phv/b/it on input line 183.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsfbi' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/sl --> T1/phv/b/it on input line 183.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsfbi on input line 187.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathsfbi on input line 187.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsfbi' in version `normal'
(Font)                  T1/phv/b/it --> OT1/phv/b/it on input line 187.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsfbi' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/phv/b/it --> OT1/phv/b/it on input line 187.
\halflineskip=\skip41
\affilskip=\skip42
\c@part=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\@indentskip=\skip43
\smallindent=\skip44
\@footindent=\skip45
\@leftskip=\skip46
\proofbox=\box26
\rpbdim=\skip47
\@stequation=\toks15
\c@subequation=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\c@figure=\count88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 1156.
\astrutbox=\box27


Found the 'amsbsy' package on the system, using it.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen104
)
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
)


Found AMS Euler Roman fonts on the system, using the 'upmath' package.

(/Users/gkv/latex/sty/upmath.sty
Package: upmath 1996/10/20 v1.0 CUP LaTeX2e package
\c@mv@upright=\count89
\c@mv@boldupright=\count90
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `upright'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/eur/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `boldupright'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/eur/b/n on input line 66.
)


Found AMS Symbol fonts on the system, using the 'amssymb' package.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip48
\bibsep=\skip49
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count91
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count92
\scratchdimen=\dimen106
\scratchbox=\box28
\nofMPsegments=\count93
\nofMParguments=\count94
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count95
\MPscratchDim=\dimen107
\MPnumerator=\count96
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count97
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/10 v0.21 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 Here is an error: a^
                        b
? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 5.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 5.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 \end{document}

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
Non-PDF special ignored!] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2775 strings out of 493014
 35477 string characters out of 6133351
 94921 words of memory out of 5000000
 6300 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 5968 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 38i,8n,28p,798b,153s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 19413 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: I see no difference between the two cases: can you edit in your `.log` for the problematic run?

Comment: Both ways run `nonstopmode` for me...

Comment: are you sure that your example is an example of the problem? If you execute the jfm class command `\checkfont` then the interaction mode would be reset to error stop mode, but this example does not do that

Comment: you are using some locally available package not in texlive  tree
(/Users/gkv/latex/sty/upmath.sty

Comment: I've added the log file. The code is exactly what I executed using pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode`  I must say I am confused by this, as it seems to me I have only had this problem recently.

Comment: This example doesn't produce that log file. You're loading several packages in your document. I guess that `upmath.sty` calls `\checkfonts`, which reinstates `\errorstopmode`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with TeX live 2016, 2017, and 2018 pretest.  Voting to close.

Comment: The jfm.cls file loads lots of packages, including upmath.sty (if it exists). upmath.sty is a package from CUP. I have renamed it so it  is not loade, but I still get the same unexpected behaviour.

Comment: as a test edit line 1099 of jfm.cls to change `\errorstopmode` to `\nonstopmode` does the problem go?

Comment: It looks like jfm.cls (or at least the version I have) reinstates \errorstopmode. So I guess that is the problem.  If I comment it out the problem goes away. Thanks for the help and pointing out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not invoked with the test file in a standard configuration but if the class ends up calling `\checkfonts` then it will "re-instate" (or in this case instate) `\errorstopmode`

You could edit the file to replace `\errorstopmode` by `\nonstopmode` on line 1099

Comment: Further investigation reveals that the jfm.cls file I was using differs slightly from the one that I pointed to originally and that @DavidCarlisle suggested I edit. I downloaded the one I used  from https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/information/instructions-contributors. This has the same header info, date and version number as the one I originally pointed to (hence I thought they were the same) but has been edited, presumably by CUP. Evidently a bug has been introduced there. This accounts for the (justified)  skepticism of various responders. Apologies.